# Proving Equality of the Induced Matrix Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, vectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to prove that the induced matrix norm satisfies $$\|A\| = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$$

Here's what I've done so far, and I'm not sure how to make the connection.

By definition, $$\|A\| = \max_{x\neq 0}{\|Ax\| \over \|x\|}.$$ Because $x\neq0$, $\|x\| \neq 0 \implies \|x\| = \alpha > 0$ for any nonzero $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ by definition of a vector norm. So, $$\begin{align}\|x\| = \alpha &\iff {1 \over \alpha}\|x\| = 1 \\ &\iff\left\|{1 \over \alpha}x\right\| = 1 \\ &\iff \|\hat{x}\| = 1. \tag{Let ${1 \over \alpha}x = \hat{x}$}\end{align}$$ I need to show that $$\max_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\| = \max_{x\neq0}{\|Ax\| \over \|x\|}.$$ Well I've shown that $$x \neq 0 \implies \|\hat x\| = 1.$$ So does it suffice to say that since $\|\hat x\| = 1$, $$\|A\| = \max_{x \neq 0}{\|Ax\| \over \|x\|} = \max_{\|\hat x\| = 1}{\|A\hat x \| \over \|\hat x\|} = \max_{\|\hat x\| = 1} {\|A\hat x\| \over 1} = \max_{\|\hat x\| = 1} \|A\hat x\|?$$

Thanks so much!

Comment: Looks good for me. Neglecting the typo $||x||=a$ which should be $||x||=\alpha$.

Comment: Whoops! Fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: Hint.$\{x:\|x\|=1\}=\{y/\|y\|:y\ne 0\}$ and $\{y:y\ne 0\}=\{r x:\|x\|=1\land 0\ne r\in R\}.$..... Remark:We usually write $\sup$ rather than $ \max$ in the def'n of $\|A\|$ because in infinite-dimensional spaces the $\max$ is not always attained.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten that a magnitude of 1 meant that it was a unit vector. And I've used the $\sup$ in norms before in my previous numerical analysis class with the $\infty$ norm. It's just our textbook uses the $\max$ definition.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the previous answer: a clearer argument (I think) is to proceed in two steps. You certainly have
$$
\max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\| = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} \le \max_{x \not= 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}.
$$

For the reverse inequality, fix $x \not= 0$. Then
$$
\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = \left\|A\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\| \le \max_{\|y\| = 1} \|Ay\|,
$$
and so taking the maximum over nonzero $x$ gives the result.